# Need to create cursor with watermark image

Tags: java, swing

I need to create cursor with transparent(watermark) image, ie if I moving cursor under for example some text I need to see that text, can somebody help me with that?

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you give more details of what you exactly are trying to achieve?

Comment: How is your need different from the functionality provided by tool tips?

Comment: I don't quite get it, don't you move your cursor _over_ something? Could you provide an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think OP needs transparent cursor. Is it?

Comment: @AndriyKushka, I'd be wary of introducing such an atypical behavior to such a commonplace component.

Comment: guys, in two words I need to create semi-transparent cursor

Comment: @Andriy Kushka in three words I need clean_up my car

Answer (score 4):

To create a custom cursor, use the [`java.awt.Toolkit.createCustomCursor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Cursor pointer() throws Exception {

        int[] pixels = new int[16 * 16];

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                new MemoryImageSource(16, 16, pixels, 0, 16));

        Cursor transparentCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                        image, new Point(0, 0), "invisibleCursor");
        return transparentCursor;
}
```