# Semi-transparent cursor

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to create cursor with watermark image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645431/need-to-create-cursor-with-watermark-image)

Can somebody help me to create  custom semi-transparent cursor in swing? I need to set some image to this cursor and for instance if I'm overlaping some text on panel I need to see this text under my cursor.

Comment: most of us remember http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645431/need-to-create-cursor-with-watermark-image

Comment: It was not correct question, now I think I asked more correctly

Answer (score 5):

Use a semi-transparent image for the cursor.  AFAIU the only image type understood by J2SE that supports partial transparency - is PNG.

---

Neither Metal nor the default Windows PLAF seems to **support** partial transparency in any way I understand it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

/** The example demonstrates how a semi-transparent image is
NOT supported as a cursor image.  It is drawn as a solid color. */
class SemiTransparentCursor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BufferedImage biPartial = new BufferedImage(
            32,
            32,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = biPartial.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,63));
        int[] x = {0,32,0};
        int[] y = {0,0,32};
        g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);
        g.dispose();

        final Cursor watermarkCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
            createCustomCursor(
                biPartial,
                new Point(0, 0),
                "watermarkCursor");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    new ImageIcon(biPartial));

                JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
                jep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
                jep.setCursor(watermarkCursor);
                try {
                    URL source = new File("SemiTransparentCursor.java").
                        toURI().toURL();
                    jep.setPage(source);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    jep);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The upshot is - I was wrong.  Using a semi-transparent icon will **not** achieve the goal.

Comment: it would be nice to see some piec of code

Comment: Just as it would be nice to see capital letters at the start of sentences, your best code attempt as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), a link to a semi-transparent 16x16 icon (or at least a 16x16 icon)..

Comment: interesting ... would have bet to having seen java created transparent cursors - and would have lost :-) Thanks for the sscce!

Comment: @kleopatra  Yes, the 'failure' result surprised me as well.  I was considering deleting the original answer, but since I had the source..  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I can't found that right now, but solved by using translucent JWindow that follows mouse on the Screen, but maybe I bet too that works in earlier Java6 versions

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem

```
public Cursor pointer() throws Exception {

        int[] pixels = new int[16 * 16];

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                new MemoryImageSource(16, 16, pixels, 0, 16));

        Cursor transparentCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                         image, new Point(0, 0), "transparentCursor");
        return transparentCursor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but this not exactly what I mean, can I do my image like glass?

Comment: i guess, its better to post a portion of your code here.

Comment: I do not have some special code, I just have a panel, on panel I have a button with some text and I need when my custom cursor move above the button I need to see the picture on the cursor and text under this picture(it should be like glass or watermark). Can I do that using the swing?