# Swing: How to set Custom Cursor as transparent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouse-cursor

I'm changing a cursor, using a PNG image (with transparency), but when I run the code below, the image doesn't look like it should.

```
public void CustomCursor()
{
    Toolkit t1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image img = t1.getImage("src/AppImages/Cursor1.png");
    Point point = new Point(0,0);
    Cursor cursor = t1.createCustomCursor(img, point, "Cursor");
    setCursor(cursor);    
}
```

This method is called in the Jframe's constructor.

[image]

This is the `cursor1.png` image, sized 25x25px.

After running the code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I use `cursor1.png` as a `JLabel`, it looks OK:

[image]

### MCVE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class CustomCursor {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    CustomCursor() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 200, 20, 200));
        Toolkit t1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJKuE.png");
            img = t1.getImage(url);
            Point point = new Point(0, 0);
            Cursor cursor = t1.createCustomCursor(img, point, "Cursor");
            ui.setCursor(cursor);
            ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomCursor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                CustomCursor o = new CustomCursor();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell why that happens?

Comment: Interesting.. As a cursor, the image translucent pixels seem to be 'filled in' as solid color - but that does not happen if it is shown in a `JLabel`..

Comment: BTW - I added the [mcve] in which I saw those results - to make it easier for others to run.

Comment: @ZMKhan just tried it out on a MAC - it looks exactly as the label. Looks like the issue may be platform dependent.

Comment: @KDM Maybe you're right.I am using absolute layout for the Jframe on Netbeans on Windows 7.Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @ZMKhan I will try converting the image to a GIF. Atleast on windows, IE had problems with PNG transparency - who knows?

Comment: @KDM ok but changing the image into gif will change the transparency

Comment: @ZMKhan gif also supports alpha channel - so it should be OK.

Comment: @KDM oh that's good.

Comment: @KDM  An important distinction between PNG and GIF is that while GIF supports **transparent** pixels PNG supports **translucent** pixels.  Those translucent pixels in the PNG image would need to be converted to either complete transparency or a solid color in the GIF.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I was viewing it on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: @AndrewThompson did it work when using GIF? For a 25x25 image one should be really a perfectionist to use translucent pixels :)

Comment: @KDM  *"did it work when using GIF?"*  I didn't try converting the image.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Uploaded converted image to http://i.imgur.com/TdNaLi6.gif - Can you please try it and tell me. TIA.

Comment: @KDM  *"Can you please try it and tell me."*  Seems good here.  My eyes aren't great, but I didn't notice much difference between the GIF (in both label and cursor) and the original PNG in the label.

Comment: @KDM I tried it as a gif but it's no use the result is the same

Comment: I know it sounds dumb but is there a way to use the Jlabel as a custom cursor?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is Windows; transparent pixels just aren't taken into account.

There is a really good answer on how to fix this on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326256/implementing-cursor-in-java-with-some-transparency). 
Another good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653100/semi-transparent-cursor).